# Impossible to select text and, then, autoformat it with Emacs+AUCtex

Tags: formatting, emacs, auctex, highlighting

With Emacs+AUCTeX, I was able to select text (with the shortcut CTRL+SPACE) and, then, format this text. For example, it was possible to select a sentence (the text is highlighted) and to press C-c C-e in order to put this text inside a center environment.

My problem is I cannot do this today. Every time I select some text, the highlighting is lost when I press C-c (the first part of the shortcut). I have this :

[image]

and press C-c C-e, the highlighting disappears after C-c and no text is formated.

Do you have an solution to this little (but very annoying) problem ?

Comment: What does C-h C-c C-e say? I get `C-c C-e runs the command LaTeX-environment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you [noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166639/31416), it's due to CUA key bindings. Even though <kbd>C-c</kbd> yanks (copies) in CUA mode, if you like them you can still use those key bindings with AUCTeX.  The solutions are described in a comment in [`cua-base.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/emulation/cua-base.el):

```lisp
;; If you really need to perform a command which starts with one of
;; the prefix keys even when the region is active, you have three options:
;; - press the prefix key twice very quickly (within 0.2 seconds),
;; - press the prefix key and the following key within 0.2 seconds, or
;; - use the SHIFT key with the prefix key, i.e. C-X or C-C
;;
;; This behavior can be customized via the
;; cua-prefix-override-inhibit-delay variable.
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem. In fact, it was a bug created by the following code in my .emacs

```
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
```

This code aims to set Emacs to handle copy/paste actions in the same way than the rest of the system. However, it creates also the described bug.